# Delphi XE7 Firemonkey Android 5.1.1 app crashing with just a TEdit on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: android, delphi

I create a fresh Android  app with Rad Delphi XE7 (Pc So win8) and test on Samsung Galaxy S7 with 5.1.1 version.

I put a TEdit on it, and run it in the Samsung Galaxy S7 and the program crashes when enter on edit component and close keyboard.

A similar problem when put image on TListBoxItem the program crashes.

The same android app work ok on Tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 with 4.2 android version.

Has anyone got a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarcadero has released a hotfix for Delphi XE7 to update the Java JNI bridge support for Android 5. Otherwise the app crashes on Lollipop. Did you download the hotfix?

http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2015-january-lollipop-hotfix-beta.html

Comment: Hello Erwin, I have not installed this update. This Wednesday downlod and install this upgrade an try to compile my apk. 

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: I have  install this hotfix for Delphi XE7 to update the Java JNI bridge .Now my Android app seems to work well. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but I have found that the VERY FIRST THING I have to do when I create a new android project is go into the project directory and delete the Android.Manifest.xml file.  If I don't do this, all kinds of craziness happens including failed deployments, failed launches, random crashes, etc.

It is also a good idea to make sure that your app only deploys to INTERNAL storage, and disable its ability to deploy to an SD card (I don't remember where that is, probably also part of the manifest).

My two cents.

Comment: I tried deleting the Android.Manifest.xml file on an existing project but the program always crashes ...

Answer (score 1):

If your PC installed old version SDK Delphi(older version 23) ,You should download new version from the Internet.

If not work,Install Delphi XE8(or DX10) in your PC.